# How to check java version on a remote Debian machine

Tags: java, ssh, debian

I am trying to check the version of java by connecting to a remote Debian machine via ssh. When I run teh command `"java -version"` it picks up the version of the environment I connected from which is my local machine.

How do I run the same command to retrive information of java installation on the remote host?

I tried

```
ssh me@remoteHost "java version "
```

but it returns me the following

```
Warning: the ECDSA host key for 'remoteHost' differs from the key for the IP address 'ip_addr'
```

Comment: There might be something wrong are you sure your ssh connection was successful and you didnt connect your local machine by mistake? Or maybe you just have same java version as the remote machine which makes you think you are picking local value

Answer (score 1):

The error you are seeing happens when authenticating to the remoteHost. You have in your `~/.ssh/known_hosts` different fingerprint for this host.

Thus the connection fails, as your computer thinks the remote host is a different one then it was *last time* (possible man-in-the-middle attack).

Answer (score 0):

This was covered in the SO Documentation project.  The information that this answer linked to is now in [Can't ssh to AWS Windows instance using Cygwin ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44773932/), which had the problem of the host key changing.